# Makehuman Importing Error

Tags: import, error, makehuman

I just made this model in Makehuman and it is ready to be imported, but everytime I try, a tradeback error pops up and my model doesn't. [image]

How do I fix that?

Comment: Since you're still using 2.79a, could it be that the MakeHuman file format has changed in the meantime and the add-on doesn't support it?

Comment: If that's true, what should I do? Please.

Comment: Check if a newer version of the add-on is available. Test if that one works.